# Comparison of available ASP.NET controls libraries

Tags: .net, asp.net, controls, components

Which .net control libraries out there would you recommend as a must have for an enterprise?

- Can be free/non free
- Should at least contain a real powerful Datagrid
- Ajax functionality

Are there any comparisons available?

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) [ASP.NET](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) control before to great effect, I'd also say check out the [DevComponents](http://www.devcomponents.com) WinForms controls...very cool stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I'll chime in for [Developer Express](http://devexpress.com/). I've used a few other component vendors in the past but in terms of the [team's involvement](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/) with their [customers and Support](http://tv.devexpress.com/) they are top notch.

[Online demos](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/NET/OnlineDemos.xml) of their ASP.Net, WPF and Silverlight components.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how match time you are willing to spend leaning how a set of UI controls work.  E.g. the DevXpress WinForms controls take a bit of getting used to, as the name of some properties are not the same as the standard Winforms controls.  However this enables DevXpress’s styling system to work.

In the past I have found that DevXpress works well for WinForms, but less well for Asp.net.  I think this is due to the fact that no two companies structure a complex web application the same way, so it is very hard for complex controls like Grid just to drop in to an existing Asp.net application. The 101 different ways of doing Ajax just makes this worse.

Some control vendors provide simple controls that are quick to learn and drop into existing code, others you have to buy into their way of doing things.  Decide if you are willing to have the control vender tell you how to structure your application.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat in for Telerik for ASP.NET/AJAX.  Yes, they may be considered "bloatware" but in with the extra functionality and UI design out of the box, I'll put with an additional 5k of data here and there.  You said "enterprise" so I assume that cost isn't a problem, if so then Telerik is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

We use Infragistics for the bulk of our needs, primarily for their grid and date controls.
In addition we use XtraReports from DevXpress for the reporting tool.

Niether are perfect but have offerred the best bang for the buck for both Windows and ASP.NET development as they provide both in one set.

I would also look at Telerik, have not used them but from what I hear they are in similar regard as Infragistics.

EDIT: Just as an added note, I find it better to stick with 1 or 2 control sets than picking a choosing individual across multiple vendors, it makes learning the controls' structure easier and easier for deployment sicne most will use some common libraries withn a suite of controls.

Answer (score 0):

Although it  depends on your project size and requriments,i recommend DevXpress and Telerik(Web/Windows).I've used ComponentArt,Telerik,DevXpress and i think Telerik is better if u are developing Web Applications.And devXpress are better in Winforms.By the way while developing,in some cases,i came across especially performance problems in Telerik Products.Nevertheless,Telerik is good choice for Web Development.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/) for enhanced datagrid capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a comparison back in 2007, see [Infragistics controls compared to devexpress and Janus controls](http://peitor.blogspot.com/2007/02/infragistics-controls-compared.html)

I would highly suggest to do a quick comparison by yourself.

1. What are your application/development goals (fast development, good UX, nice look and feel, performance, win or web, which control is a must have, ...)
2. Collect possible different vendors
3. Make a quick test tool with the different vendors
4. Let different developers rate the controls/vendors
5. Blog about your work and let us know :-)